# I can't seem to figure out a way to include text and image in a same ForEach

Tags: swiftui, foreach

```
 
    let items = Array(1...9).map({"Image\($0)"})
    let items1 = Array(11...14).map({"Image\($0)"})
    let items2 = Array(15...20).map({"Image\($0)"})
    let items3 = Array(21...25).map({"Image\($0)"})
    let items4 = Array(26...39).map({"Image\($0)"})
    
    
    struct MyData: Identifiable{
        var id = UUID()
        var title: String
        
    }
    
    
    var mData = [
        MyData(title: "Men's Clothing"),
        MyData(title: "Men's Shoes"),
        MyData(title: "Men's Accessories"),
        MyData(title: "Children's Clothing"),
        MyData(title: "Women's Clothing"),
        MyData(title: "Women's Shoes"),
        MyData(title: "Women's Accessories"),
        MyData(title: "Children's Shoes"),
        MyData(title: "Children's Accessories")
        
    ]
    
    
    
    @State var text = ""
    
    let layout = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 80)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 80)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 80)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 80))
      
    ]
    
 
    
   
    
    var body: some View {
        
       
        NavigationView{
           
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                SearchCategories(text: $text)
                
                Spacer()
                
                LazyVGrid(columns: layout, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders] ) {
                    Section(header: Text("Clothing & Accessories")
                        .font(.system(size:16))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(height: 0)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .background(Color("MainF"))
                            
                            
                             
                             ) {
                    
                    
                        ForEach(mData.filter({"\($0)".contains(text) || text.isEmpty})){ item in
                        
                        VStack{
                            
                            
                        Text(item.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .font(.system(size: 10))
                        
                                                    
                    }
                }
                  
            }
                        
        }      
               LazyVGrid(columns: layout, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders] ){
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Vehicles")
                        .font(.system(size:16))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(height: 0)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .background(Color("MainF"))
                    ) {
                    ForEach(items1, id: \.self) {
                        item in
                        VStack{
                        Image(item)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .padding()
                            
                            Button("Motorbike"){
                                
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                           
                        }
                    }
                    
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to show a gird of image and text together. But I am not able to implement that at once. It's either text grid or image gird.

I have implemented mData for all the text I want below the image that I am pulling from items array. I'm trying to achieve the grid layout through LazyVgrid. I have also added pinnedViews to add headings for each grid.

I am recently learning switfUI and solution for this will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you put an image of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @GuillermoJiménez.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQDtl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is very helpful to post a buildable MRE. The question itself was well asked.

Here is an example to get you started. The key is to have the image and the text contained in the same data model, so they are accessible at the same time. I added an `image` variable to the `MyData` struct, and you can see how that allows the view to come together easily. Since I don't have access to your images, I used `SF Symbols` instead.

```
struct MyData: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let image: String
}

struct GridTextAndImageView: View {
    
    let myData = [
        MyData(title: "Pencil", image: "pencil"),
        MyData(title: "Trash Can", image: "trash"),
        MyData(title: "Paper Airplane", image: "paperplane.fill"),
        MyData(title: "Umbrella", image: "umbrella.fill"),
        MyData(title: "Megaphone", image: "megaphone.fill"),
        MyData(title: "Speaker", image: "speaker.fill"),
        MyData(title: "Flashlight", image: "flashlight.on.fill"),
        MyData(title: "Camera", image: "camera"),
        MyData(title: "Wrench", image: "wrench"),
        MyData(title: "Screwdriver", image: "screwdriver.fill"),
        MyData(title: "Paintbrush", image: "paintbrush"),
        MyData(title: "Printer", image: "printer"),
        MyData(title: "Briefcase", image: "briefcase.fill"),
        MyData(title: "AirPods Max", image: "airpodsmax"),
    ]
    
    let layout = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 80)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 80)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 80)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 80))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 25, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders] ) {
                    Section(header: Text("Various SF Symbols")
                        .font(.system(size:16))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(height: 0)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(Color.orange)
                    ) {
                        ForEach(myData) { item in
                            VStack{
                                Image(systemName: item.image)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .padding()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                    .background(LinearGradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.blue.opacity(0.4)], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                                Text(item.title)
                                    .frame(alignment: .center)
                                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```